# Database with web interface

Tags: python, database, django, development-environment

I want to do a little project to lerarn few things and how it's done. I want to create a database with web interface. I was considering sql and PHP, but few people told me it is better/easier/faster to do this using sql and Python/Django. I searched a little for some ideas butdidntseem to find anything usefull.

But i don't know even where to start, can enyone help me - know where i could find some usefull literature/trainings? And later how can i move this app to a different place? (like from my pc to for example a server?) If anyone would have some usefull training it would be awesome.

I have some knowledge of both Python and SQL but never did anything like this.

Would really appreciate help.

Best Regards,
Iscario

Comment: Start from here djangobook.com.

Comment: Do you want to create an web application with database or you just want to manage your database via a web browser?

Comment: i would say, dont start with db-site, it could be difficult on the way. start with small application with interesting functions so that you can learn things. the best place to learn: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/

Comment: Do NOT use djangobook.com. It is terribly outdated. They even warn you on the first page. Use the official tutorials on djangoproject.com

Comment: @PSJayPeng It would be just a web app with db, some simple queries to the db and wieving the results.

Answer (score 0):

Kenneth Love did a presentation at pycon 2014 that is a crash coarse on Django. This seems like a good start. There are also Django sessions on the pycon videos page.

[Video of the presentation](http://pyvideo.org/video/2562/getting-started-with-django-a-crash-course)